# videojs javascript plugins on firefox fail to load

Tags: video.js

I have identified a simple use-case where plugins don't work on firefox.

```
http://107.20.191.154/video-js/test.html
```

If you click this link, the "speed" plugin works on chrome and safari, but not for the latest version of firefox.

Any ideas why its not working?   Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
$(function(){
  var video = videojs("example_video_1", {
    controls: true,
    //more options
  });
});

<video … data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch":false}'>…
```

Both having a `data-setup` attribute on the video element and the `videojs()` function would set up video.js. You shouldn't use both. One is "winning" on Firefox, he other on other browsers. You should use one method or the other, including all options you need there.